# How to specify shape of network with Graph function?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have the code you see below which displays the network that you see. However, I want to structure it so that it is flipped horizontally, and the 2, 3, 4, 5 quadrilateral is a square, and so that the 1, 2, 3 triangle is equilateral. How can I do this in Mathematica? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Did you try any other layouts? `GraphLayout -> "LayeredEmbedding"` is pretty close and 2,3,4,5 is square but the 1,2,3 triangle is not quite equilateral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5},
 VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center],
 VertexSize -> 0.1,
 VertexCoordinates -> {4 -> {0, 0}, 5 -> {1, 0}, 2 -> {0, 1},
   3 -> {1, 1}, 1 -> {1/2, 1 + Sqrt[3/4]}},
 ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 2}}`

```
 g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 5, 4 -> 5}, 
  PlotTheme -> "IndexLabeled",
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {1, 2, 2}}, 
  ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

and post-process to change the orientation:

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[-Pi/2]@GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

[image]